# CSS sidebar overlapping container content

Tags: css

I am working on a dashboard for my application right now and am running into some issues with my layout structure.

[image]

I want the content within the container to be nested in between the sidebar and the navigation bar. I am using bootstrap for this along with a custom set of styles.

Here is the HTML for the sidebar:

```
<div class="fixed-sidebar fixed-sidebar-light">
    ...
</div>
```

Here is the css for the sidebar:

```
.fixed-sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 22;
    width: 270px;
    min-height: 1000vh;
    box-shadow: 0 0 34px 0 rgba(63, 66, 87, 0.1);
}
```

Here is the HTML for the header:

```
<header class="header" id="site-header">
...
</header>
```

Here is the CSS for the header:

```
height: 70px;
background-color: #3f4257;
padding-right: 70px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 21;
```

Why would the container content still be pushed to the right with that component there?

Here is a codepen with all the code in it.

https://codepen.io/teecp/pen/zyOpvd

Comment: could you please share this on jsfiddle or codepen so one could better help.

Comment: @Aditi https://codepen.io/teecp/pen/zyOpvd

Comment: @TrentonTyler if an answer below adequately resolves your problem, please choose it as an accepted answer. If not, please clarify the end goal of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sidebar fixed position means that it is no longer inline with the rest of your header and containers in the DOM. It just looks like your container with the content isn't colliding with the sidebar at larger breakpoints because the container has a max-width of 1300px and `margin: 0 auto`, leaving just enough auto margin on the ends of the container to not "collide" with the sidebar.

[image]

A hotfix for this (I don't fully agree with the structure) would be the following adjustment:

**CSS**

```
.container-sidebar {
  margin-left: 270px; 
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="container-sidebar">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- content or markup here -->
  </div>
</div>
```

In my opinion, sidebars are meant to be minimized to allow maximum screen real-estate - so in that particular case, the sidebar should slide in and out of the left side of the page. Having this UI would change your order of markup, but thinking ahead, maybe that's what you're going for.

Answer (score 1):

This particular layout is something I'm working on at the moment, I have a sidebar which I can toggle, as well as a top navigation bar, and I want only to change the content located "inside" those two components.

I'm not exactly sure if this is the behavior you want for the sidebar, but it can be easily adjusted, for example if what you want is for the sidebar to just expand on top of the content without pushing it

I followed this particular tutorial which has helped me a lot and I definitely recomend: https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar

I built the layout like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        // open or close navbar
        $('#sidebar, #content, footer').toggleClass('active');
    });
 });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#content {
  width: calc(100% - 230px);
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#content .panel {
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
#content.active {
  width: 100%;
}

#top-bar {
  background-color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  z-index: 997;
  width: inherit;
  position: fixed;
}
#top-bar .navbar {
  padding: 20px;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 230px;
  max-width: 230px;
  background: #FCFCFC;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -230px;
  top: 0;
  /* top layer */
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #0000001f;
}
#sidebar.active {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav id="sidebar" class="active">
            <h1>Sidebar</h1>
        </nav>
        <div id="content" class="">
            <header id="top-bar" class="">
                <div class="navbar navbar-expand container-anchor">
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-outline-dark mr-3">
                        <i class="fas fa-align-left"></i>
                        <span>Toggle Sidebar</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="panel" class="panel container-fluid">
              <section>
                <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis obcaecati voluptatum magni ducimus mollitia excepturi rem iste illum, quod dolorum doloribus, nostrum reiciendis perferendis animi porro sapiente nesciunt? Excepturi eveniet iusto rerum quis illo repudiandae tempora, harum amet nesciunt officia libero ullam magni aliquam numquam? Doloremque aliquam in atque harum aut mollitia aspernatur doloribus veritatis porro et cum, nulla quidem perspiciatis at rerum magni provident quibusdam nam id cumque reiciendis assumenda consectetur! Placeat quod alias eligendi error repudiandae, numquam repellat! Voluptatem dolore iste praesentium nulla ducimus fugit sed perspiciatis. Soluta nisi, esse porro reprehenderit illo commodi hic placeat nobis aspernatur. Necessitatibus nihil cupiditate, ut odit optio soluta? Corrupti quam omnis provident vel eos aliquam non blanditiis totam iste. Repellendus dolorem voluptatem atque, laborum, suscipit amet exercitationem eum ipsum, quaerat qui ratione aut architecto repellat sint! Quas earum exercitationem amet recusandae pariatur odit aspernatur sint perferendis non porro, harum quidem. Ea.
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis obcaecati voluptatum magni ducimus mollitia excepturi rem iste illum, quod dolorum doloribus, nostrum reiciendis perferendis animi porro sapiente nesciunt? Excepturi eveniet iusto rerum quis illo repudiandae tempora, harum amet nesciunt officia libero ullam magni aliquam numquam? Doloremque aliquam in atque harum aut mollitia aspernatur doloribus veritatis porro et cum, nulla quidem perspiciatis at rerum magni provident quibusdam nam id cumque reiciendis assumenda consectetur! Placeat quod alias eligendi error repudiandae, numquam repellat! Voluptatem dolore iste praesentium nulla ducimus fugit sed perspiciatis. Soluta nisi, esse porro reprehenderit illo commodi hic placeat nobis aspernatur. Necessitatibus nihil cupiditate, ut odit optio soluta? Corrupti quam omnis provident vel eos aliquam non blanditiis totam iste. Repellendus dolorem voluptatem atque, laborum, suscipit amet exercitationem eum ipsum, quaerat qui ratione aut architecto repellat sint! Quas earum exercitationem amet recusandae pariatur odit aspernatur sint perferendis non porro, harum quidem. Ea.
                    </p>
                    
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis obcaecati voluptatum magni ducimus mollitia excepturi rem iste illum, quod dolorum doloribus, nostrum reiciendis perferendis animi porro sapiente nesciunt? Excepturi eveniet iusto rerum quis illo repudiandae tempora, harum amet nesciunt officia libero ullam magni aliquam numquam? Doloremque aliquam in atque harum aut mollitia aspernatur doloribus veritatis porro et cum, nulla quidem perspiciatis at rerum magni provident quibusdam nam id cumque reiciendis assumenda consectetur! Placeat quod alias eligendi error repudiandae, numquam repellat! Voluptatem dolore iste praesentium nulla ducimus fugit sed perspiciatis. Soluta nisi, esse porro reprehenderit illo commodi hic placeat nobis aspernatur. Necessitatibus nihil cupiditate, ut odit optio soluta? Corrupti quam omnis provident vel eos aliquam non blanditiis totam iste. Repellendus dolorem voluptatem atque, laborum, suscipit amet exercitationem eum ipsum, quaerat qui ratione aut architecto repellat sint! Quas earum exercitationem amet recusandae pariatur odit aspernatur sint perferendis non porro, harum quidem. Ea.
                    </p>
              </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is another example which creates an overlay on top of the page's content

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
        $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('.overlay').on('click', function () {
        $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });

    $('#dismiss').on('click', function () {
        $('.overlay').toggleClass('active');
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
    });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 998;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* display .overlay when it has the .active class */
.overlay.active {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}

#sidebar {
  min-width: 350px;
  max-width: 350px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: -350px;
  /* top layer */
  z-index: 9999;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

#sidebar.active {
  margin-right: 350px;
}

header {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="wrapper">
            <nav id="sidebar" class="">
                <button type="button" id="dismiss" class="d-block btn btn-success">
                Close Sidebar
                </button>
                
                <div>
                   Sidebar Content
                </div>
                
            </nav>
        <main id="content">
            <header class="top-menu">
                <div class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light container">
                    <h2>Top Bar</h2>
                    <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="nav-link ml-auto btn btn-outline-dark">
                       Toggle Sidebar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </header>
            
            <section>
              Content goes here
            </section>
            
        </main>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep sidebar always appear in the left and do not want to open or close it then it can be achieved by using only bootstrap and no need to write custom css.

Use bootstrap navbar for the header and remove any extra css which you write for header otherwise it will override the bootstrap one.

Do not use `fixed-sidebar` class and instead of that restructure your template as per bootstrap pattern you need to do the following and you will not need any custom css for that too:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <!--Sidebar-->
            <div class="col-md-3 col-xl-2">
                <a class="logo" href="/">
                    <div class="img-wrap">
                        <img width="150" src="/assets/logo-white-cad55691e551f40916535bcbe93173c0d76adc0bf6db8d15de937e475874f76a.png" />
                    </div>
                </a>
                <div class="mCustomScrollbar ps ps--theme_default" data-mcs-theme="dark">
                    <ul class="left-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="/">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="left-menu-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-home"><path d="M3 9l9-7 9 7v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2z"></path><polyline points="9 22 9 12 15 12 15 22"></polyline></svg>
                                <span class="left-menu-title">Dashboard</span>
                            </a>            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/questions">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="left-menu-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-help-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><path d="M9.09 9a3 3 0 0 1 5.83 1c0 2-3 3-3 3"></path><line x1="12" y1="17" x2="12" y2="17"></line></svg>
                                <span class="left-menu-title">Questions</span>
                            </a>            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/categories">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="left-menu-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-list"><line x1="8" y1="6" x2="21" y2="6"></line><line x1="8" y1="12" x2="21" y2="12"></line><line x1="8" y1="18" x2="21" y2="18"></line><line x1="3" y1="6" x2="3" y2="6"></line><line x1="3" y1="12" x2="3" y2="12"></line><line x1="3" y1="18" x2="3" y2="18"></line></svg>
                                <span class="left-menu-title">Categories</span>
                            </a>            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/tournaments">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="left-menu-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-grid"><rect x="3" y="3" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="14" y="3" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="14" y="14" width="7" height="7"></rect><rect x="3" y="14" width="7" height="7"></rect></svg>
                                <span class="left-menu-title">Tournaments</span>
                            </a>            </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="/users">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="left-menu-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-users"><path d="M17 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H5a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="9" cy="7" r="4"></circle><path d="M23 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-3-3.87"></path><path d="M16 3.13a4 4 0 0 1 0 7.75"></path></svg>
                                <span class="left-menu-title">Users</span>
                            </a>            </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!--Main content-->
            <div class="col-md-9 col-xl-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <p>Anything in this content area is being squished under the sidebar when being scaled down</p></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div data-react-class="StatCard" data-react-props="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Questions&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:1}"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div data-react-class="StatCard" data-react-props="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Categories&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:2}"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div data-react-class="StatCard" data-react-props="{&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Tournaments&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:1}"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Bootstrap itself provide lot of capabilities you just need to follow the documentation and you will get all the things required. Always try to use framework's feature instead of defining custom css or the overriding existing one. Only write custom css when there is no way to acheive by framework's any component provided.

Also if you want to hide that fixed sidebar for small devices and show them in a dropdown than you can use bootstrap's collapse feature for small devices.